# How to switch which graphics card is used for video output

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, monitor, xserver

I have two graphics cards: A GTX 1070 Ti and a Quadro K620. I need to use the Quadro for my monitor output so the more powerful 1070 can be devoted to computation. Whenever I plug a monitor into the Quadro, it just stays black, and my main monitor goes black two. I don't want to use dual monitors.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and nvidia 390 drivers

## [SOLVED]

I went into the NVIDIA X Server Settings and altered the Selection and Configuration and restarted the x server a few times.